# keycloak: print the redirect_uri into html template

Tags: keycloak

I need to print into html template of the login page of keycloak the redirect uri used after the login

Example:

```
<script>
  doSomething({redirectUri: "${redirectUri}"});
</script>
```

There is a variable or parameters that contains the redirect uri?